# Cordova, Visual Studio and xCode 8

Tags: node.js, cordova

since two months I try to run my cordova app... before the update to xCode 8 everything worked fine. When I want to run the app from Visual Studio via Remotebuild i get this error:

> Signing for "BlankCordovaApp1" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>   Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

my build.json looks like this:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "developmentTeam": "secret"
    },
    "release": {
      "developmentTeam": "secret",
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "packageType": "ad-hoc"
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me guys I'm so desperately with this issue...

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 8 and iOS 10 you should now use `--codeSignIdentity="iPhone Developer"` both for "debug" and "release" configurations.
So `build.json` should look like this for newer versions:

`{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}`

See this [PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/pull/659/files) for the details.